# TreeView in a ScrollView in Kivy - No Scroll

Tags: python-2.7, kivy

I'm working on a kivy app that pulls data from an sqlite3 database and populates a TreeView with it.  The TreeView becomes too large to fit on my screen when I expand a few of the groups so I want to put it inside a ScrollView so I can still scroll down and see the items that have gone off the bottom of my screen.  I can get a basic ScrollView to work, but when I put my TreeView inside it there is no scrolling and the top part of my TreeView is off the top of my screen.

I have trimmed down the code into this working example of the problem that runs without a .kv file:

```
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TreeViewButton(Button, TreeViewNode):
    pass

modGroups = [u'Fruit', u'Fruit', u'Meat', u'Dairy', u'Dairy', u'Fruit']
modItems = [u'Apple', u'Pear', u'Spam', u'Egg', u'Milk', u'Banana']
modDict = dict()
modDictUnique = dict()

def populate_tree_view(tv):
    modDict = zip(modGroups, modItems)
    print modGroups
    print modItems
    for k, v in modDict:
        if k not in modDictUnique:
            modDictUnique[k] = [v]
        else:
            modDictUnique[k].append(v)
    sortedGroups = modDictUnique.keys()
    sortedGroups.sort()
    #print modItems
    #print modDictUnique
    n = tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='Food', is_open=True))
    for group in sortedGroups:
        g = tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='%s' % group), n)
        for item in modDictUnique[group]:
            tv.add_node(TreeViewButton(text='%s' % item), g)

class POSFMApp(App):

    def build(self):
        layout = GridLayout(cols=1, spacing=50, size_hint_y=None,width=800)
        layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))
        #for i in range(30):
        #    btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(480, 40),
        #                 size_hint=(None, None))
        #    layout.add_widget(btn)
        tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Tree One'), hide_root=True, indent_level=4, minimum_height=5000)
        populate_tree_view(tv)
        layout.add_widget(tv)
        root = ScrollView(size_hint=(None, None), size=(800, 700))
        root.center = Window.center
        root.add_widget(layout)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    POSFMApp().run()
```

In my actual app, modGroups and modItems are populated from an sqlite3 database, but this example presents the problem without having to mess around with sqlite3.  I put in the (commented out) lines:

```
#for i in range(30):
#    btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(480, 40),
#                 size_hint=(None, None))
#    layout.add_widget(btn)
```

from this [kivy ScrollView example](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/blob/master/examples/widgets/scrollview.py) to show that if I uncomment these lines and comment out the three lines about my TreeView

```
tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Tree One'), hide_root=True, indent_level=4, minimum_height=5000)
populate_tree_view(tv)
layout.add_widget(tv)
```

Then I can get a working ScrollView with a scroll bar on the right as expected when I use my mouse's scroll wheel.

My best guess is that the TreeView doesn't tell the ScrollView how long it is vertically so the ScrollView doesn't realize it needs to scroll on the y-axis.  That's just a guess, though.

How can I get a TreeView to work inside a ScrollView so I can scroll (especially on the y-axis) through my TreeView?

Comment: Can you add snapshot of the GUI, I am looking for something similar to what you have implemented

Answer (score 5, accepted):

a) Using a [GridLayout](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.gridlayout.html) just for one child, pease don't. I'll asume that it's a left over from when/if you add more children to it.

b) Documentation of [TreeView](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html) states that it has [minimun_height](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html#kivy.uix.treeview.TreeView.minimum_height) property which indicates the minimum width/height needed to hold all it's children. The [Treeview](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html) does not change it's height on it's own depending on the no of children. You should update (in this case) [TreeView](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html)s height to it's [minimum_height](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.treeview.html#kivy.uix.treeview.TreeView.minimum_height)... `tv.bind(minimum_height=tv.setter('height'))`
c) taking into account the information provided in the points above, you can just do::

```
tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Tree One'), hide_root=True, indent_level=4)
tv.size_hint = 1, None
tv.bind(minimum_height = tv.setter('height'))
populate_tree_view(tv)
root = ScrollView(pos = (0, 0))
root.add_widget(tv)
```

Here is the entire code including these changes so one can just copy and paste the code to a .py file and run it.

```
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeViewLabel
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class TreeViewButton(Button, TreeViewNode):
    pass

modGroups = [u'Fruit', u'Fruit', u'Meat', u'Dairy', u'Dairy', u'Fruit']
modItems = [u'Apple', u'Pear', u'Spam', u'Egg', u'Milk', u'Banana']
modDict = dict()
modDictUnique = dict()

def populate_tree_view(tv):
    modDict = zip(modGroups, modItems)
    print modGroups
    print modItems
    for k, v in modDict:
        if k not in modDictUnique:
            modDictUnique[k] = [v]
        else:
            modDictUnique[k].append(v)
    sortedGroups = modDictUnique.keys()
    sortedGroups.sort()
    #print modItems
    #print modDictUnique
    n = tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='Food', is_open=True))
    for group in sortedGroups:
        g = tv.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text='%s' % group), n)
        for item in modDictUnique[group]:
            tv.add_node(TreeViewButton(text='%s' % item), g)

class POSFMApp(App):

    def build(self):
        #for i in range(30):
        #    btn = Button(text=str(i), size=(480, 40),
        #                 size_hint=(None, None))
        #    layout.add_widget(btn)
        tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text='Tree One'), hide_root=True, indent_level=4)
        tv.size_hint = 1, None
        tv.bind(minimum_height = tv.setter('height'))
        populate_tree_view(tv)
        root = ScrollView(pos = (0, 0))
        root.add_widget(tv)
        return root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    POSFMApp().run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Add hight to TreeView then it will scroll. Like this.

```
ScrollView:
            id: kr_scroll
            do_scroll_x: False
            TreeView:
                id: trvMenu
                root_options: { 'text': 'Home', 'font_size': 15}
                hide_root: False
                indent_level: 4
                size_hint_y: None
                height: self.parent.height*2
```